# Do GHC rewrite rules know to recognize syntactic sugar?

Tags: haskell, ghc

For example with lists, if I write a rule with the LHS of `myFn [x]`, will it also be able to fire when the programmer writes `myFn (x:[])`? or will I have to write a separate rule for every possible syntax?

Comment: We all know that list construction like `[a,b,c]` is just sugar for `a:b:c:[]`, so these two expressions are equivalent, but the second one is better form for pattern matching.

Comment: Syntactic sugar doesn't matter for rewrite rules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Re-write rules get de-sugared.  So a re-write rule like

```
{-# RULES
  "myFn/singleton"    forall x. myFn [x] = myOtherFn x
#-}
```

will be stored internally as

```
forall x. myFn (x:[]) = myOtherFn x
```

It's then applied to the de-sugared form of the program.  (All optimization in GHC occurs on the de-sugared form of the program).

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that purely syntactical things like this don't matter; the rule will fire either way.

What you *will* find to be a problem is that `myFn` might have been inlined by the time GHC tries to use the rule (so there will be nothing for it to fire on). In general, figuring out exactly when to enable your rule(s) is the hard part!